# invalid characters in the URL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request
ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL.
here is my url:
http://dev2.socialboards.no/demo/questions/&page=2

Answer (score 4):

You should use `?` instead of `&`:

```
http://dev2.socialboards.no/demo/questions/?page=2
```

If you had multiple parameters then you would separate them with `&`:

```
http://dev2.socialboards.no/demo/questions/?page=2&foo=bar
```

Comment: Hi Mark problem here how this url work (http://socialboards.no/demo/questions/&page=2) and show my the message of second page

Comment: @NareshKumar: I don't know. Do you have the source code? Maybe you can figure it out by looking at the source code.